# Spring-MVC: Controller working in one project but not the other(404 not found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public class ToDoController 
 {  
   @GetMapping
   public String print()
   {
     return "Hello";
   }
 }
```

I as well run the spring app as follows:

```
 import java.util.Collections;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Startup 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Startup.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
                .singletonMap("server.port", "9005"));
        app.run(args);
    }
```

}

Now when i run localhost:9005/ I do see the following pop up

2021-05-19 12:05:00.961  INFO 40900 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-19 12:05:00.961  INFO 40900 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-19 12:05:00.962  INFO 40900 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms

Which I think means some connection is working but I am getting a 404 error on the web page.

Now what is odd is that when I copy paste both these classes to another project(in a package I have worked previously and know works), the code runs fine. However if in the same project I created a new package and placed new controllers in that package with a new Startup class, the controllers also do not work(404 error).

I built this project with eclipse and included all dependencies in class path, I never had to make a web.xml file and most of the solutions I found require you to change that file.

Any help would be appreciated as I haven't done anything different from the project/package that does work and the one's that do not.

Comment: What packages do `Startup` and `ToDoController` reside in?

Comment: You just made me realize problem by that simple question. My start up and controller are in different packages. When i put it in same package it works, when i dont it does not work. How can i make it work so controller is in one package and the startup is in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What packages do `Startup` and `ToDoController` reside in?

If the controller resides in a package that is not a 'descendant' of the `Startup` package, it will not get picked up by component scan by default. You need to use `@SpringBootApplication.scanBasePackages` to point Spring at the additional packages to scan.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it by adding this to the StartUp Class:@ComponentScan(basePackages = "RESTAPI.controllers"). I am guessing for multiple packages it would be an array.